# Numpy compare two 3d array and find identical arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays,

```
mat = np.array(
    [
        [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]],
        [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]],
        [[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
    ]
)
mat2 = np.array(
    [
        [[0,1],[0,1],[0,2]],
        [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]],
        [[2,0],[2,2],[2,2]]
    ]
)
```

I would like to find all the arrays in axis 2 which are the same in both `mat` and `mat2` and turn them into an array of zeros. Differently speaking, if each array `mat` and `mat2` was a RGB image, I would like to find the pixels with the same R,G,B values and return an image with the same pixels set as (0,0,0) and the rest of the pixels intact.

So the output I'm trying to achieve with the above arrays would be this:

```
[
    [[0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
    [[0, 0], [2, 2], [0, 0]]
]
```

I have tried the following code:

```
operated = np.where((mat2-mat==0).all(axis=2), np.array([0,0]), mat2)
```

However it would say:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (2,) (3,3,2)
```

I think it's because it returns just one `True` or `False` for each array in axis 2 which instead should be `(True , True)` if pixel is same, or `(False, False)` if subtraction should not be done.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[[[0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [2, 2], [0, 0]]]`? Specifically first row of output looks wrong.

Comment: @Divakar It's a typo, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Use `keepdims=True` with `.all()`.

Comment: @Divakar I'm sorry, but I'm still new with numpy so I'm not sure what exactly needs to be done. Can you elaborate or include code?

Comment: Google for the docs - `numpy.all()`.

Comment: Ah that seems to do the trick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to replace the values in the array according to the following condition:

```
np.where((mat == mat2).all(axis=2,  keepdims=True), [0,0], mat2)

array([[[0, 1],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [2, 2],
        [0, 0]]])
```

Where `(mat == mat2).all(axis=2,  keepdims=True)`:

```
array([[[False],
        [ True],
        [ True]],

       [[ True],
        [ True],
        [ True]],

       [[ True],
        [False],
        [ True]]])
```

Returns a mask of the same dimensions as `mat` which you can use as a condition for `np.where`. Then you simply need to specify whether to replace these values by a `[0,0]` or by `mat2` depending on the result.

Comment: Would it be possible to do subtraction only if subtraction on first item in array axis 2 is within a specific range?

Comment: Hmm could you give me an example? And you mean replace not substract right?

Comment: For example,  `3 < mat2[y][x][0] - mat[y][x][0] < 5?return (0,0,0):mat2[y][x]`

Comment: For each element within the last dimension then?

Comment: Yes I meant replace of said condition is met.

Comment: Just the first element within each element in the last axis is used to determine if it should be substituted.

Comment: hmm only the first let me see

Comment: If I use images as an example, if the subtracted value of red values is within a specific range, that pixel should be (0,0,0) else leave it alone.

Comment: Don't have time now. Will update later if I come up with a solution :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort.